# Do we need assertions in addition to the provider interaction declaration with Pact?

Tags: unit-testing, pact

I'm working on `pact` and I'm often see example that do assertions on request's response along the contract testing part like

```
test('Check endpoint for post questions on success', async () => {
  await provider.addInteraction(…);

  const response = await createQuestion(…);

  expect(response.status).toBe(201); // <------------
});
```

#### Question

Is there added value, to contract testing, to add such assertions on the request's response? Or declaring the interaction embed the whole value of contract testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, no.

I wouldn’t do that assertion personally, as all that that is just checking is that Pact did what you asked it to do - i.e. testing the mock.

Think of a Pact test as a unit test of your API client, that just so happens to also produce a contract.

Therefore, it’s much more important to check the behaviour of your API client being tested, and Pact will actually check the real response of the provider later on.

In your case, I'd expect `createQuestion` to return some useful data (or potentially a `Question` domain model), so you should check that object is correct. e.g.

```
const question = await createQuestion(...);
expect(question.id).toBeDefined();
```

Comment: You are still doing an assertion (`expect().toBe…()`), the `createQuestion()` from my code base return a `Promise<void>`, we have integration tests, next to the contract ones, that assert the method is called with correct arguments that all. So I'm wondering if the lack of assertion in the contract test can result in false-positive

Comment: Yes, of course, you are still doing assertions - that's the point of a unit test. I'm emphasising that the assertions should be on the behaviour of `createQuestion` (your code, built on assumptions about the HTTP interaction), not on the HTTP response, which is simply a reflection of the mock you configured.